# How to prevent sorting at pandas dataframe from list form dict.?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code and want to prevent the sorting when inserting to the dataframe. Data must be ordered as i entered the data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgPKu.png)
Can you help?

```
import pandas as pd

data_list = ['5894_5t64z0_20200301_0400.mseed', '5894_5t64z0_20200301_0800.mseed','5894_5t64z0_20200301_1200.mseed', '5894_5t64z0_20200301_2000.mseed']


df_1 = pd.DataFrame()

list01 = []

for events in data_list:

    dict01 = {
        'sensor_names': events[0:11],
        'years': events[12:16],
        'months': events[16:18],
        'days': events[18:20],
        'hours': events[21:23],
        'min': events[23:25],
        'secs': '00'
    }
    keys = list(dict01.keys())
    list01.append(dict01)

df = pd.DataFrame(list01)
df
```

Comment: I literally run the same code, and it shows to me the order in which the dictionary has been set up. Kindly rerun this code and check

Comment: i re-runned many times, never saw what you saw

Comment: Here is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtWnw.png